# Expose Minikube Cluster IP

Tags: kubernetes, minikube

[image]

I have a deployment with services running inside minikube on a remote linux vps, these services have Cluster IP with no external IP, I would want to access these services from a web browser

Answer (score 0):

Either you change the service type **LoadBalancer** which will create the External for you and you can access the specific service using that.

**OR**

Setup the **ingress** and **ingress controller** which can be also useful to expose the service directly.

**OR for just Development use not for Prod**

```
kubectl port-forward svc/<service name>  5555:<service port here>
```

This creates the **proxy** tunnel between your K8s cluster and local. You can access your service now at `localhost:5555`

Answer (score 0):

You need to first understand the purpose of ClustrIP, as the name suggests it can only be used inside the cluster. You can use NodePort to expose your service but that still is a restricted choice and won't be beneficial for what you are aiming. You need a Load Balancer to expose your service to the outside world.

You can use load balancer available with Minikube, it's called Metallb to expose your services inside minikube for internet traffic.

The last difficulty would be to comprehend that you still need a web server with reverse proxy rules that can forward the traffic to minikube just like a web server(Apache or NGINX) in front of Tomcat. [Here](https://zubair-teach.github.io/posts/ingress-into-baremetal-minikube/) is a complete example to show the same in much simpler terms on a bare-metal machine.